# Upgrade PostgreSQL JSON column to JSONB?

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

After upgrading to PostgreSQL 9.4, how do I convert all my JSON columns into JSONB columns?

I don't mind losing any duplicate keys and whitespace.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

```
ALTER TABLE t ALTER COLUMN j TYPE jsonb USING j::text::jsonb;
```

Answer (score 7):

In the context of Rails, here is an ActiveRecord migration alternative:

```
def change
  reversible do |dir|
    dir.up { change_column :models, :attribute, 'jsonb USING CAST(attribute AS jsonb)' }
    dir.down { change_column :models, :attribute, 'json USING CAST(attribute AS json)' }
  end
end
```

I tested this on a table with 120 000 records, each record having four `json` columns and it took me about a minute to migrate that table. Of course, it depends on how complex the `json` structure is.

Also, notice that if your existing records have a default value of `{}`, you have to add to the above statements `default: {}`, because otherwise you'll have `jsonb` columns, but the default value will remain as `'{}'::json`.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone looking for a solution with `alembic` (specifically, I use `flask + alembic + postres 15.3`):

```py
import sqlalchemy as sa
from alembic import op
from sqlalchemy.dialects import postgresql


def upgrade():
    op.alter_column('system_info', 'phones', type_=postgresql.JSONB, postgresql_using='phones::text::jsonb')


def downgrade():
    op.alter_column('system_info', 'phones', type_=sa.JSON(), postgresql_using='phones::json')
```

Can't tell much about it, I'm no expert, but in my case the migration goes smoothly (which means I haven't noticed any data damage or even changing). Some details you can find [here](https://github.com/inveniosoftware/invenio-records/issues/171). I posted `downgrade` also because in `alembic` you need to have rollback strategy.