# How should I upgrade from bradjasper's django-jsonfield to Django's built-in jsonfield?

Tags: json, django, postgresql, jsonb

I have a Postgres 9.4 / Django 1.8 database that uses bradjasper's `django-jsonfield` package. (See https://github.com/bradjasper/django-jsonfield )  It works well, but I would like to upgrade the existing data to use Postgres 9.6 and Django 1.9's built-in JSONField. (See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#jsonfield )  This will allow more robust searches of JSON content.

How do I upgrade the old database to the new one?

What I've tried:
I tried inserting a pair of schema migrations to

- Convert the bradjasper JSONField to a TextField, including running the migration. (This shouldn't change the database, since bradjasper stores data as a string.)
- Run Django's `dumpdata` command.
- Updated Postgres & Django versions.
- Run the migration to convert the TextField to Django's JSONField. (This should be a change in the database, from a `text` or `json` to `jsonb`.)
- Run Django's `loaddata` command.  This gives an error like: `u"[] (type <type 'unicode'>) is not a valid list for field url_methods"]: (myapp.mytable:pk=1) field_value was '[]'` 
  I'm looking at [postgresql migrating JSON to JSONB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28202158/postgresql-migrating-json-to-jsonb) and [Upgrade PostgreSQL JSON column to JSONB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28075479/upgrade-postgresql-json-column-to-jsonb) but am hoping to minimize the custom SQL.

Comment: Did you also edit/delete the existing migrations? before doing loaddata?

Comment: I ran the migrations up through the convert-to-textfield step before the dumpdata, then ran the convert-from-textfield migration before the loaddata. Edited the steps-tried bit to be more clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ALTER COLUMN command from @tometzky via [Upgrade PostgreSQL JSON column to JSONB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28075479/upgrade-postgresql-json-column-to-jsonb)
does this with surprisingly little hassle:

- sudo -u postgres psql -c 'ALTER TABLE mytable ALTER COLUMN "myfield" TYPE jsonb USING "myfield"::text::jsonb;' mydatabase

I didn't need Django's loaddata / dumpdata commands or a custom migration.

I did have some issues getting pg_upgrade to work the way I wanted, since it wasn't on the default path and wanted to change the port used by Postgres during the upgrade. To get around *that*, I did the following:

- pg_ctl -D /etc/postgresql/9.4/main/ stop
- use `sed` on postgresql.conf to change which port it used
- install Postgres 9.6
- pg_ctl -D /etc/postgresql/9.6/main/ stop
- cd /var/log/postgresql
- run pg_upgrade
- cd back to the original working directory
- apt-get -y remove postgresql-9.4 postgresql-client-9.4 postgresql-server-dev-9.4
- service postgresql start

Answer (score 11):

Upgrade Postgres first. If all works upgrade Django.

Only if everything works as expected you can start writing your field migration.

You want to go from:

```
from jsonfield import JSONField

class MyModel(models.Model):
  json = JSONField()
```

To:

```
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import JSONField

class MyModel(models.Model):
  json = JSONField()
```

Steps:

1. Add the new Postgres JSON field named `json_new`.
2. Make migrations. Do NOT migrate yet.
3. Dive into the migration file and write a data migration (RunPython) to populate the new json field.
4. Make migrations.
5. Delete the old field. Delete the old import.
6. Make migrations, migrate.
7. Rename new field to old field name. `json_new` > `json`.
8. Make migrations, migrate.
9. Done.

Step 1:

Use `import ... as ...` to prevent collisions. Your model will look like:

```
from jsonfield import JSONField as OldJSONField
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import JSONField

class MyModel(models.Model):
  json = OldJSONField()
  json_new = JSONField()
```

Step 3:

You need to `RunPython` in your migration see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/migration-operations/#runpython
Also note how to import your model.

The actual data migration will be something like:

```
for obj in MyModel.objects.all()
    obj.json_new = obj.json  
    obj.save()
```

Step 4 - 7:

Make sure you create separate migrations for deleting and renaming. If you do all code changes and create a single migration, then Django will think you dropped `json_new`. But you want to drop `json` and rename `json_new` to `json`. Small, but important difference.

It isn't to hard to reduce the migration steps. But that requires to write some code by hand. I'm lazy and like Django to write this code for me.

Comment: I like that you met my soft requirement of doing this without custom SQL, but the loop over individual records bothers me. (I have several fields on different tables, and each table may have a few thousand records.)  Also the SQL turned out to be easier than I feared. I'm giving up a thumbs-up but accepting my own answer.

Comment: You could perform data migration in `RunPython` with a single query by using an `F` expression : `MyModel.objects.update(json_new=F('json'))`

Comment: Yes! `F` will work and is faster and less load on the db.

Comment: In step 4, I guess you mean "run migration" instead if "make migrations"?